# Shapefiles not showing up in assigned directory in R - says it exists but can't find it

Tags: r, directory, kernel-density

I created kde polygons in R and set the directory for output and when I run the code it works and says it exists but the shapefiles are not showing up in my folder.

Here is my code:

```
`Ei121130 <- read.csv('gps_data_121130.csv')

Ei121130fr <- filter(Ei121130, between(as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 
as.POSIXct("2013-10-20 00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), as.POSIXct("2013-10-22 23:59", 
format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")))

gps_points121130fr <- SpatialPoints(Ei121130fr[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")], 
                        proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

kde121130fr <- kernelUD(gps_points121130fr, h = "href", grid = 100, kern = "bivnorm")
kde50121130fr <- getverticeshr(kde121130fr, percent = 50)

plot50121130fr <- plot(kde50121130fr, col = "red", lwd = 2, main = "50% KDE of GPS data 
121130fr")

outdir <- "Shapefiles2"

#Create directory if it doesn't exist
if(!dir.exists(outdir)){
  dir.create(outdir)
}

#Converting data to Simple Features format
kde50_121130frdata <- st_as_sf(kde50121130fr)
#Using the st_write() function from the sf package to write the shapefile
st_write(kde50_121130frdata, "kde50_121130fr.shp")`
```

The "Shapefiles2" folder is created and the code says they exist but for some reason the folder is empty and I don't know what is going wrong.

Here is my sample code (I am struggling how to attach an actual file of it):

DeployID    Ptt Instr   Date    Type    Quality Latitude    Longitude   Error radius    Error Semi-major axis   Error Semi-minor axis   Error Ellipse orientation   Offset  Offset orientation  GPE MSD GPE U   Count   Comment
121130  121130  SPOT    10/20/2013 14:34    Argos   B   20.956  -157.434
121130  121130  SPOT    10/20/2013 16:26    Argos   2   20.947  -157.254
121130  121130  SPOT    10/21/2013 0:03 Argos   B   20.903  -157.145
121130  121130  SPOT    10/21/2013 1:45 Argos   1   20.993  -157.369
121130  121130  SPOT    10/21/2013 3:38 Argos   2   21.001  -157.314
121130  121130  SPOT    10/21/2013 3:38 Argos   2   21.001  -157.314
121130  121130  SPOT    10/21/2013 14:18    Argos   B   21.122  -157.431

Comment: What exactly is the output you get when you run this? It seems off you are defining the `outdir` variable but then are not using in your `st_write` command. When exactly do you want the files to do? What's your current working directory?

Comment: My current working directory is the Documents folder where the "Shapefiles2" folder was created and I want for those shapefiles I created to save to that folder so I can input them into ArcPro.

Comment: I tried to put the path (outdir) in the st_write command and it didn't work either but it's possible I had that wrong.

Comment: It is showing up as a polygon in my global environment, I just don't know why it is not saving to the folder so I can export. Before when I was using rgdal, it worked.

Comment: Your shapefile should be in your working directory, Documents, as you said. You can double check your working directory with `getwd()`. Also, `st_write()` with the default argument `append=NA`  won't overwrite a file and will throw an error, pay attention to what is outputed in the console.

Comment: RIght, that's what I don't understand. My working directory is correct. The output directory "Shapefiles2" was created successfully in my working directory but none of the saved shapefiles are showing up in the output folder.

Comment: Also, yes, I noticed that about append = NA and instead put append = FALSE to overwrite it.

Comment: This is my output when I run the code:

Deleting layer `kde50_121130fr' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Writing layer `kde50_121130fr' to data source `kde50_121130fr.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Writing 1 features with 2 fields and geometry type Polygon.

Comment: This output is good news. Have you tried `list.files()` directly in R? Also, your code in your original post has a wild backtick and the end. Did you tried to write something else?  Ex
`library(sp)
data("meuse")
meuse %>% st_as_sf(coords=c("x","y")) %>% st_write("tmp.shp")`

Comment: Probably because your `st_write(kde50_121130frdata, "kde50_121130fr.shp")` writes to current directory, not to `st_write(kde50_121130frdata, "Shapefiles2/kde50_121130fr.shp")`.

Comment: Try this `st_write(kde50_121130frdata, paste0(outdir, "/kde50_121130fr.shp"))`. As MrFlick, VinceGreg and Grzegorz have mentioned, you're using only the filename in `st_write()` and thus it will write to your working directory, not the `outdir` you created earlier.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much!! That makes much more sense.